# Circle border custom

Tags: html, css

I want to get the shape in picture

```html
<div style="width: 70px; height: 70px; border:1px solid #F35652;border-top:10px solid #F35652; border-left:10px solid #F35652; border-radius: 50%; line-height: 55px; font-weight: bold; color: #000; margin-left: -14px;">1</div>
```

[image]

Comment: If your example comes from another website, why don't you just inspect the element to see how they did it in the first place?

Comment: I would try to accomplish this using [`::before / ::after`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)

Comment: @ArpennSardin design from XD design

Comment: @FadyNabil provide a link?

Comment: Look into SVGs.

Comment: @AHaworth Ah okay Great idea for me